# How to correctly call an asynchronous method on each render of a component in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, hook

**Scenario:**
A statistics view on a website that has to render three different data tables, one at a time.

**Code:**
The view is a component and inside of it i have three buttons, each one sets a variable that renders a component with a table, depending on that variable value, the table hast to call an api with different information.

the structure is as follows:

**statistics component:**

```
<template>
  <div class="buttons">
    <div @click="setStatisticSection('POSITIONS')">POSITIONS</div>
    <div @click="setStatisticSection('RESULTS')">RESULS</div>
    <div @click="setStatisticSection('FIXTURE')"">FIXTURE</div>
  </div>
  <data-table v-if="activeStatistic === 'FIXTURE'" data="fixture" environment="view" :loading="loading"></data-table>
  <data-table v-if="activeStatistic === 'RESULTS'" data="results" environment="view"></data-table>
  <data-table v-if="activeStatistic === 'POSITIONS'" data="positions" environment="view"></data-table>
</template>
<script>
import dataTable from '@/components/Table.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    'data-table' : dataTable,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      activeStatistic: 'RESULTS',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setStatisticSection(section) {
      this.activeStatistic = section;
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

**table component:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <table class="table__fixture">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>FECHA</td>
          <td>HORA</td>
          <td>CONF</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-if="tableData.data" v-for="row in tableData.data" :key="row.id">
          <td>{{row.fecha | date}}</td>
          <td>{{row.fecha | time}}</td>
          <td>{{row.zona}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="table__postions">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>POSICIÓN</td>
          <td>PTS</td>
          <td>ARR</td>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-if="tableData.data" v-for="row in tableData.data" :key="row.id">
          <td>{{row.posicion}}</td>
          <td>{{row.arrastre}}</td>
          <td>{{row.pj}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="table__results">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>FECHA</td>
          <td>HORA</td>
          <td>CONF</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-if="tableData.data" v-for="row in tableData.data" :key="row.id">
          <td>{{row.fecha | date}}</td>
          <td>{{row.fecha | time}}</td>
          <td>{{row.zona}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  props: ['data', 'environment'],
  data() {
    return {
      tableData: '',
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    if (this.data === 'fixture' && this.environment === 'view') {
      this.fetch('fixture', 1, 15);
    } else if (this.data === 'positions') {
      this.fetch('positions', 1, 100);
    } else if (this.data === 'results') {
      this.fetch('results', 1, 15);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async fetch(data, page, perPage) {
      console.log('Fire!');
      const thiss = this
      if (data === 'fixture') {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get(`apilinkhere/public/fixture?page=${page}&per_page=${perPage}`);
          thiss.tableData = response.data;
        } catch (e) {
          throw new Error(e);
        }
      } else if (data === 'positions') {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get(`apilinkhere/positions?page=${page}&per_page=${perPage}`);
          thiss.tableData = response.data;
        } catch (e) {
          throw new Error(e);
        }
      } else if (data === 'results') {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get(`apilinkhere/public/results?page=${page}&per_page=${perPage}`);
          thiss.tableData = response.data;
        } catch (e) {
          throw new Error(e);
        }
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**Problem:**

The case is that the mounted hook only fires on the first component render, and not on each render (say when i change the activeStatistic) and if i put the method to call the api to for a different table data on the Updated hook, as it explains on the documentation, it drives to an infinite method call chain.

Vue documentation says that i would watch for a variable to perform this, but i'm not really sure how to do that or where to watch this variable from.

**IMPORTANT:**

You may see some inconsitencies on the code i show (filters applied to variables in the template that doesnt exist on the script, for example) this is because i cleaned the code i copypasted a little bit for the sake of readability, it doen't affect the problem or the information you need to offer a solution. if you see some language inconsistencies, it is due to the fact that the original code has some words in spanish.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution:**

i simply added a watcher to the "data" prop